# How to eliminate the extra line produced by my for loop?

Tags: python, for-loop

I am trying to print out a right-angled triangle by using a for loop, however, even though I got the shape that I intend to have, the outcome always comes with an extra line underneath the input question, I want to know how to delete it?

Here is my code:

```
height = int(input('Enter height: '))
for i in range(height+1):
    print(i * '*')
```

and the output is:

```
Enter height: 6

*
**
***
****
*****
******
```

What I want to have:

```
Enter height: 6
*
**
***
****
*****
******
```

Comment: You already have what you want to have, but your code probably produces something else (remember: in a `for`-loop, the upper bound is exclusive, and the lower bound is zero).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code is printing i=0, which generates the blank line.

Try the below:

```
height = int(input('Enter height: '))
for i in range(1, height + 1):
    print(i * '*')
```

Comment: True, height + 1 makes more sense.

Comment: I see what the problem is now, thanks a lot!